# Voltage and series circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Suppose I have 2 series circuit. One will have resistance $R_1$ and the other $R_2$. Now my question is why is voltage difference same across both resistor? The top part of both resistors should have same voltage but bottom part I am not sure. They will dissipate different amount of heat. I cannot reason through the bottom part.

Answer (score 1):

In a series circuit, the voltages are different when the resistances are different If $U$ is the total voltage across both resistances, the drop over the fist one will be $U_1=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2 } U$ and across the second one $U_2=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2 } U$. This comes from Kirchoff’s law of current.

I think you rather meant a circuit in parallel where the voltage drop is the same for both resistances. This is due to Kirchoff’s law of voltages. The resistances are parallel, so they form a closed loop. Since the voltage drop is independent of the path in a steady state, you have to have an equal voltage drop. However, to compensate, different amount of current will flow, writing $I$ the total incoming current, you have the current $I_1=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2 } I$ through the first resistance and $I_2=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2 } I$ across the second one, hence the heuristic of path of least resistance.

In either case, you are correct for the unequal dissipation, whenever the resistances are different. Hope this helps and tell me if you find some mistakes.

Comment: I am saying two series circuit not a single circuit with two resistance.

Comment: Then the volatge across the resistance will depend on the applied voltage if they are different circuits. Could you sketch out what you have in mind?

Comment: they have same voltage different resistance

Comment: I don’t understand your problem then. By construction, they will have the same voltage drop. Please try to do a sketch.